# What's meaning of formula should used?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, moderation, on-hold-questions

Today I saw the question [Denoting the set of initial segments of a binary sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/545564/denoting-the-set-of-initial-segments-of-a-binary-sequence), which searches for a formula. It got put on hold as an unclear question. I guess that the unclearness was from meaning of formula. So can any one explain applicable meaning for it?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't make sense of your title, so I left it untouched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that this question shouldn't be closed.

I had just filed a reopen request in the [designated thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/11481/43351).

---

**Edit**: it has now been reopened.